# Is it possible to open a Visual Studio 2008 Database Project with VS2008 Development Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, database-project

I have a Visual Studio 2008 Team System Development Edition installed and a solution that contains a Database Project. Is there any addon that I can install to make Studio load this project?

Answer (score 1):

If your development edition came from MSDN, you should have access to database edition via MSDN, too (based on [this article](http://www.cio.com/article/451622/Microsoft_Announces_Visual_Studio_2010._Developers_Respond.?page=3) and my personal experience):

> As of October 1 [2008], those who belong to the Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) *and*  currently own Visual Studio Team System 2008 Development Edition or Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition will receive for free the Visual Studio Team System 2008 Development Edition, Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition, Visual Studio 2005 Team System for Software Developers and Visual Studio 2005 Team System for Database Professionals.